# Wired connection problem on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, connection

I've been surfing through google for an answer on this computer with windows, but I can't find any solid answer. I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus EEEPC netbook which had windows 7 starter. For some reason when i connect the internet cable (that im using to connect this computer to the internet) it doesn't work. I'm not sure if wireless is working since i don't have a router yet. I'm brand new to ubuntu so I'm really at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more information. What you mean by "it doesn't work"?
Did you configure your network-manager.
Show result of `sudo ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue from time to time on my Acer Netbook. Sometimes you have to wait for the Lan0 connection to be recognized. Either you can wait for a 'wired socket' notification to appear, or you can go into the network manager and see if the wlanO or eth0 option appears.

If it doesn't show up, you may have to configure it manually as your network may not support DHCP.

For ease of reference, here is the entry on the 11.04 Manual

**[Connect to a wired (Ethernet) network](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html)**

> To manually set your network settings:
>
> Click the network menu on the top panel and click Edit Connections.
>
> Find the network connection that you want to set up manually. For
>   example, if you plug in to the network with a cable, look at the Wired
>   tab.
>
> Click the connection you want to edit to select it, then click Edit.
>
> Go to the IPv4 Settings tab and change the Method to Manual.
>
> Click Add and type the IP address, network mask and default gateway IP
>   address into the columns in the Addresses list. Press Enter when
>   you've finished typing each address.
>
> All three of these addresses must be "IP addresses", which will be
>   four numbers separated by periods (e.g. 123.45.6.78).
>
> Type the IP addresses of the DNS servers you want to use, separated by
>   commas.
>
> Click Save. If you are not connected to the network, go to the network
>   icon on the top bar and connect to it. Test the network settings by
>   trying to visit a website or look at shared files on the network, for
>   example.

Comment: Where do i find all of this information